# How to insert role associated with user in users_roles table through UI?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rolify

Can someone help me on how to insert new record in users_roles table using rolify gem?

Comment: can you please post code snippet you tried.?

Answer (score 1):

That is in the document of Rolify gem.

```
user = User.find(1)
user.add_role :admin
```

You can have a form which will submit the role and in controller you will do something like I mentioned above.

For reference see [this link](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify#4-add-a-role-to-a-user)